# Why window.fbAsyncInit function didn't gets fired from some mobile devices?

Tags: android, ios, facebook, mobile-safari, mobile-chrome

I have an application configured to support FB authentication, but it seems to be **`window.fbAsyncInit()`** didn't gets called from some of my mobile devices whereas it works for desktop and some mobile devices.

```
Works for : Android(Marshmallow OS) with Default browser
            Desktop with Chrome and Firefox

Not works for: IOS with Safari browser
               Android(Lollipop) with chrome browser
```

Does anyone know the reason?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does the SDK load properly on those devices? And privacy extensions or similar that might be blocking it?

Comment: Thanks for the response.

Can you please tell me how can I check whether the SDK load properly on those devices"?

Comment: Don’t know which of those browsers have build-in debug tools or can connect to an external machine for debugging purposes. If none are available, I’d try something like jQuery’s getScript to load the SDK, and see if that is successful.